# I have written the below code to check the elements of array

Tags: java

I have written the code below to check the elements of array. I got the required answer. I just want to know what changes should I do so that it gives me the output as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5.`

Also when I write `a[]` instead of `b[]`, the code gives me the error `a is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])`. Could you please help me?

```
class ArrayDemo15
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        int b[]=new int[5];
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(b[i]+""+);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "what changes should I do so that it gives me the output as 1,2,3,4,5." You haven't got anything in your array, you'll get 0,0,0,0,0. Think about it, I'm sure you'll work it out.

Comment: @xagyg not getting please explain

Comment: There are so many fundamental problems in the understanding here (from the original question and the comments of the OT), that the only real solution to the problem is "Read a tutorial or book".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I just want to know what changes should I do so that it gives me the output as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`"*

If you just want to print those numbers then you dont need array at all. Just use for loop like

```
int counter=1;
for (counter=1; counter<=4; counter++)
    System.out.print(counter+", ");
//after loop print last element without comma
System.out.println(counter);
```

---

But if you insist in improving your code and using array continue reading this answer...

Right now your code gives compilation error in `System.out.println(b[i]+""+);` since `+` in this case is two argument operator and you give it only one argument. Change it to something like

```
System.out.print(b[i]+", ");
```

I used `print` instead `println` since you don't want to have new line signs between numbers.

Also currently your array is filled with zeros, because all new arrays are filled with some default values: 

 - for arrays of *primitive numbers type* (int, byte, double and so on) default value is 0,

 - for *primitive boolean* it is false, 

 - and for *Objects* (like Strings) it is null.

So you need to fill your array first with your values. To do that you have two options

1. iterate over array and set every element

   ```
   for (int index = 0; index < b.length; index++) {
       b[index] = index + 1;
   }
   ```
2. provide all values while creating array, like

   - `int[] b1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` this version can be used only with reference
   - `int[] b2 = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` this version doesn't need reference and can be used everywhere for example as argument of some method that accepts array of int like `Arrays.sort(new int[]{ 5, 3, 1, 4, 2 })`

When all elements of array are set to correct values you need to print it. You can do it with built-in utility as [A. R. S. pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14310255/1393766) `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(b))` or do it yourself with loops for example

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length - 1; i++) {// b.length - 1 I don't want to
    // print last element here since I don't want to add comma
    // after it
    System.out.print(b[i] + ", ");
}
// now it is time for last element of array
System.out.println(b[b.length - 1]);
//since b[]={1,2,3,4,5} b.length=5 so it will print b[4] -> 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

And look at the argument of your main method - it's called `a`, so you can't change the name of `b` to `a` because that would result in two variables with the same name. Maybe you should change it to something like `main(String[] args)`.

---

**Relevant Documentation**

- [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29)

Comment: @Akshay Add the line `import java.util.Arrays;` to the top of the source file.

Comment: It is giving me the below output

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: @Akshay Yes - is that not what you wanted? The elements of your array are all 0.

Comment: I want them to display as 1 2 3 4 5 instead of 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: That's not how your array is initialized which is why your receiving all `0`'s.

Comment: "Arrays.toString(b)" don't work because "b[]" is empty... if you want print "a[]" change to "System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));"

Comment: @Akshay to init array... change "int b[]=new int[5];" to "int b[]=new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5 };"

Answer (score 0):

```
int b[] = new int[5];
```

Your line of code is just creating a new int array that has 5 blank elements in it.

```
int b[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

This line will give you an array, called b, with the elements 1,2,3,4,5.

As for the second question, you have the variale `a[]` in your main paramaters.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize an array without specifying initial values, Java sets every element in the array to a default value based on its type; the default avlue for int is 0. If you want [1,2,3,4,5] as your array instead of [0,0,0,0,0], you can set the contents of the array at initialization, i.e. `int b[] = {1,2,3,4,5};`. You can also set the array in the for loop by adding a line before the call to `println`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   b[i] = i+1;
   System.out.println(b[i]);
}
```

The reason you're getting that error is because you can't redeclare the type of a variable, only reassign it.  For example,

```
int a = 4;
int a = 5;
```

is not allowed, but

```
int a = 4;
a = 5;
```

is allowed. In the main method, the array `a` is declared as a `String[]`, and cannot be redeclared as an `int[]`.